# routes with parameters on express mongodb and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Good evening,
I have a problem with my node express mongodb and mongoose server.
my routes with parameters do not work.
do we need to clarify or add something?

Very important
thank you

Comment: Can you share your complete code?

Comment: thank's 
the code is posted

Comment: you can edit the original post to provide information requested

Comment: Params are not ignored. you have to call your endpoint like that: `http://localhost:4000/user/a@a.com`. Your code just works.

Answer (score 0):

You are not receiving any data, because you are saving in mongodb the `req.body` attributes.

In order to do that you have to post data in request body.

Here is a curl example:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:4000/signup/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "idade":123,
    "nome":"teste",
    "profissao":"programador top",
    "email": "a@a.com"
}'
```

Also for return your data correctly you have to change a little your code from get request.

```
app.get('/user/:email', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("login 1", req.params);
  User.findOne({ email: req.params.email })
  .then(user => res.status(200).json(user))
  .catch(error => res.status(404).json({ error }));
    
  });
```

Here is a curl for a working get request:

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:4000/user/a@a.com' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

Tested local and it is working with success.

Comment: Please , could you explain me the difference between
(A)
` http: // localhost: 4000 / user? email = test @ hotmail.com`

and
(B)
`http: // localhost: 4000/user/test@hotmail.com`
I had an express server on a mysql connection
and I passed my parameters as in (A)
and that worked

Comment: In (A) you are using `query strings` in (B) you are using `query parameters`. In simple terms  a query string is the part of a URL (Uniform Resource Locater) after the question mark (?). While in (A) you are structuring your request URL with a placeholder for any value when you defined your route as `app.get('/tag/:email', (req,res)`. You can do a deep  detailed read about it in thomas fielding dissertation about Design of Network-based Software Architectures. Here is the link: https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm